# Apache won't start after upgrade

Tags: apache-2.2

I upgraded apache on RHEL4 using Jason Litka's RPM repository (actually I upgraded PHP, but it updated apache for me), and now apache won't start. There are no errors on startup, it just won't start. I tracked it down to conf.d/ssl.conf and particularly the line Listen 443.
Please let me know if you need more information

**Edit**
If it helps, here's the output from strace: http://pastebin.com/f6ee7ed61

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there was something it didn't like about the vhost setting.

Answer (score 0):

Is there something else listening on port 443?

Comment: No. Was my first inclination also. I checked with lsof -i:443, which turned up nothing.

Answer (score 0):

hey if you do a httpd -l what modules are listed? Is the mod_ssl included in the Apache conf?

Also are you sure no errors appear in var/log/messages or elsewhere

J

Answer (score 0):

If you pull out ssl.conf does it start? If so, maybe the mod_ssl and apache version do not the correct module magic number. You may need to update mod_ssl as well or even openssl using the alternate repo.